# How to copy rows from one worksheet to another worksheet (start at specfic row) by using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet which like this:

[image]

Now, I have implemented generating different categories worksheets (i.e Internet, Desktop Publishing, Business worksheet), so I need to insert these product with their name and price to their category worksheet from Rows 4, like this:
[image]

This is my VBA Code:

```
Sub task()
Dim Start As Integer
Start = 3

While Cells(Start + 1, 2).Value <> ""
    Start = Start + 1
Wend

Dim category_range As Range
Set category_range = Range("B4:B" & Start)

Dim List As Object
Set List = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim Rng As Range

For Each Rng In category_range
    If Not List.Exists(Rng.Value) Then
        List.Add Rng.Value, Nothing
    End If
Next Rng

Dim arr(), k As Variant
ReDim arr(List.Count)

Dim wdnmd As Integer
wdnmd = 0
For Each k In List.Keys
    arr(wdnmd) = k
    wdnmd = wdnmd + 1
Next k

Dim category_index As Integer
For category_index = 0 To List.Count - 1
    Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets("Data")).Name = arr(category_index)
    With Sheets(arr(category_index))
        .Columns("A").ColumnWidth = Sheets("Data").Columns("A").ColumnWidth
        .Range("A3").Value = "Product"
        .Range("B3").Value = "Price"
        .Range("A1").Value = "Products in the " & arr(category_index) & " Category"
    End With
Next category_index

Dim target As Range
Set target = Range("A4:C" & Start)
Dim entry As Range, i As Integer
Dim target_worksheet As String
For i = 4 To Start
    target_worksheet = Cells(i, 2).Value
Next i
End Sub
```

By the last line of my code, we will determine which category the product belongs to, i.e we know that which worksheet contains the product. What is difficult for me is how to make the code always insert new entries start at the `4th` row of these three worksheets? I think VBA should have a built-in function to complete this operation. I have tried `rows.insert` and `copy` `paster` methods to be puzzled, but I did not know how to implement this part.

Comment: Using a cuss word as a array variable is inappropriate.

Comment: Please use workplace-appropriate language on Stack Overflow, not language which may be offensive to some people or groups of people. Please see: [Are expletives (cursing, swear words or vulgar language) allowed on SE sites?](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/are-expletives-cursing-swear-words-or-vulgar-language-allowed-on-se-sites). Keep in mind that using offensive language tends to result in people reacting poorly to your posts (i.e. they may downvote). In addition, do you really want a future employer to see you using such language in a situation which is intended to be professional?

Answer (score 1):

To cut the rows you need to define what you want to cut and set it to a variabel like "Variabel"

```
Variabel.EntireRows.Cut
```

after that you can try this:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("InsertDesiredWorksheet").range(A2).Columns.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
```

I've done something similar where above code worked, you might need to tweak it so you can use the variabel for category and name the intended worksheet after it.

Comment: Thank you very much, but for me i need to `Variabel.EntireRows.Copy` rather than `Cut`

Answer (score 1):

This will copy 5 rows from `Sheet1` to `Sheet2` starting at row #4, just make sure the ranges are equal, e.g. copying 5 rows range and pasting into 5 rows:

```
Sheets("sheet1").Range("1:5").Copy Sheets("sheet2").Range("4:9")
```